# Zendframework 2 Call services using static methods

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

In a controller I can call services using this code

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyServiceName');
```

It works pretty cool.

I created a custom library in zf2.(/vender/API)
I need to have access to all services that were loaded using static methods.(if it's possible)
Just for example.

 I created this custom class.(The idea of this (custom) class is different and it must be independent)

```
class Test extends AbstractModel {
    protected $identifier;
    protected $fullName;
    protected $someText;

    public function getService(){

    }
}
```

How can I call loaded services using static methods/or something that I don't know inside my class?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? If you want to have access to all services, just `__construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) { ... }`

Comment: Ocramius  I'm thinking about to create FactoryInterface and implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that! It has been discussed before, you can eventually read the [discussion on the mailing list](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Fundamental-question-Why-isn-t-the-service-manager-super-global-td4659184.html), which has some good examples too.

Assuming your class `Test` needs access to the service locator for some reason, the correct approach is to instantiate it with the service locator as hard dependency:

```php
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Test extends AbstractModel
{
    // ...

    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function doFoo()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator->get('FooService')->foo();
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you can either instantiate it with `$test = new Test($serviceLocator);` or define it in a factory, and let the service locator itself provide you an instance:

```php
namespace MyApp;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Test' => function ($serviceLocator) {
                    return new \Test($serviceLocator);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

This basically makes service `'Test'` available across your application.

Anyway, there's two big flaws in what you just created:

- there's pitfalls you should be aware of while using service location. This is a problem of [service location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) itself due to its nature:

  1. you are binding your code to a service locator, while it may not be a problem of your class to retrieve instances of other services. Inject them instead if they are well defined and always the same
  2. you are using strings for service names in your classes. That makes it very hard to port your code to another application where the service names may be completely different
  3. your code may fail due to a service locator failure (not found service). This failure may be delayed by the fact that you are accessing services only when required. That may not be trivial to debug on complex applications
- you are hereby trying to use services (and a service locator) in a model/entity. This misconception/misuse may come from the fact that you are used to the [active-record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), where a lot of logic is part of the object representing a DB record, like in `Zend_Db` in ZF1. Since services in ZF2 are quite easy to define and use, please move such logic in a service. What you described above is a class that is more like a value-object or entity, and should not contain complex business logic.

I also wrote a blogpost on [why you should use use IOC instead of service location](http://ocramius.github.com/blog/zf2-and-symfony-service-proxies-with-doctrine-proxies/) if you are interested (the second paragraph describes the pitfalls of service location).